# VS2017 to WSL connection Failure

Tags: visual-studio-2017, windows-subsystem-for-linux

WSL connection to visual studio never happy with my login details, I followed these guides below:

[Guide 1](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2017/02/08/targeting-windows-subsystem-for-linux-from-visual-studio/)

[Guide 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45465756/visual-studio-2017-cannot-connect-to-wsl-says-username-and-password-are-wrong)

[Guide 3](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/WritingAndDebuggingLinuxCApplicationsFromVisualStudioUsingTheWindowsSubsystemForLinux.aspx)

I follow the instructions:

```
Host Name = localhost
Port = 22
User name = User name I created for WSL
Authentication Type = Password
Password = Password I created for WSL user name.
```

with credentials above it does not like username password.
I change port number in WSL config file to 2222, then it does not like port number.

I return to port 22, disbale ssh broker on windows, and still no luck.

Need help getting WSL to connect to my Vs2017 using latest update.

Any help much appreciated, cheers

Comment: Have you looked at [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44088855/connecting-to-the-windows-subsystem-for-linux-from-visual-studio-2017)? I had a similar problem which as far as I know is down to WSL still being in Beta, so I'm still waiting for a solution.

Comment: thanks for the link exact problem , will give insider build a try

Comment: @IkoLogs please try this - https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/69075cf3-a1b7-4c4c-bbac-807e46426dc8/unable-to-add-ssh-connection-to-remote-system-in-visual-studio-2017?forum=vsdebug

Hope this will help you.. :)